# How do i remove a dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a the following code to load a treeview with data using jstree plugin and plugin was attached to index view of MVC4

```
<div id="jstree_demo_div">
    <ul>
        <li class="jstree-closed">Root node 1
            <ul>
                <li class="c1">child1</li>
                <li class="c1">child2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="jstree-closed">Root node 2
            <ul>
                 <li class="c1">child3</li>
                 <li class="c1">child4</li>

           </ul>
        </li>
  </ul> 
</div>

<div id="Divtxt1"></div>
<h2>Index</h2>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
       $(document).ready(function () {//{ "theme": { "icons": true }
           $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();

           $(document).on('click', '.c1', function () {
               var nodeText = $(this).text();
               //alert(nodeText);
               $('#Divtxt1').append('<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid black" ' + 'id=' + nodeText + '>' +
                   '<textarea style=width:100px;height:100px;visibility:visible;' + 'id=txta' + nodeText + '>' + nodeText +
                   ':</textarea>')
               .append('<input type="button" class="del" value="Del"' + 'id=' +'btn-' + nodeText + ' />')
               .append('</div><br />');
           });

           $(document).on('click', '.del', function () {
               var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
               var coll = btnId.split('-');
               alert(coll[1]);
               //alert( $(this).attr('id') )
               alert($(this).find('textarea[id=txta'+coll[1]+']').text());
               alert( $(this).closest('div').html() );
           });
        });
    </script>

    }
```

the above code will dynamically add divs with `<textarea>` and a button when the user clicks a `child node` of any parent. The purpose of the button is to delete its `div`( so it will remove the textarea and also button with it). But the problem i have is the button does not delete it.

another is the following code:
  `alert($(this).find('textarea[id=txta'+coll[1]+']').text());`

should display the text in the textarea but it does not either. So how do i remove the div the button is in?

Comment: `$(this).closest('div').remove();` will remove the div

Comment: @StephenMuecke from what i have tried with this code removed the whole divs collection, assume there are three divs added, when i click the last one it will remove all divs further  when i use this code alert( $(this).closest('div').html() ); it will show all the divs

Comment: `alert($(this).closest('div').find('textarea').val());` to alert the value of the textarea

Comment: @abbatat isn't that what you wanted remove the div ? then @ Stephen 's comment answers the question

Comment: @abbatat: No, Stephen's code will only remove the single div that's the closest ancestor element to `this` (and its contents, of course). Not all divs.

Comment: Then the code your tried is not what I showed :) - it removes the div surrounding the button

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, But that's what OP has asked for - _"delete its div (so it will remove the textarea and also button with it)"_?

Comment: @guradio not the whole set of div tags only just the div whos buttons was clicked

Comment: @abbatat, The code I showed only removes the one div - the one surrounding the button (assuming the html your adding is valid) - suggest you show an example of the html your dynamically generating

Comment: @StephenMuecke let me rephrase the problem in few word, when i click any child node each will add a separate div that has a textarea and a button. so if i click all four child nodes it will create four divs. So if i click the button of the last div it should only remove that last div

Comment: @abbatat, Again, That is exactly what the code I showed will do. If its not, then show the actual html your generating

Comment: @StephenMuecke funny the demo worked but mine did not!

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Right. I was saying that you were correct, and abba's comment that that would remove all divs was not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems, first they way you have used `append()` is not proper, it doesn't work like string concatenation. Second you need to delete the parent `div` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //{ "theme": { "icons": true }
  $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();

  $(document).on('click', '.c1', function() {
    var nodeText = $(this).text();
    //alert(nodeText);
    var html = '<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid black" ' + 'id=' + nodeText + '>' + '<textarea style=width:100px;height:100px;visibility:visible;' + 'id=txta' + nodeText + '>' + nodeText + ':</textarea>' + '<input type="button" class="del" value="Del"' + 'id=' + 'btn-' + nodeText + ' /></div><br />';
    $('#Divtxt1').append(html);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="jstree_demo_div">
  <ul>
    <li class="jstree-closed">Root node 1
      <ul>
        <li class="c1">child1</li>
        <li class="c1">child2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="jstree-closed">Root node 2
      <ul>
        <li class="c1">child3</li>
        <li class="c1">child4</li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="Divtxt1"></div>
<h2>Index</h2>
```

Comment: your answer is bit more clear so i have marked as answered but i cannot give marks till i receive some 15 points

Answer (score 1):

Try this :You can find the parent div using `closest()` and then call `remove()` method on it to remove the div and its child elements.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.del', function () {
     var $parentDiv = $(this).closest('div');  
     $parentDiv.remove();   
});
```